# Convert Script to Exe

Tags: xml, automation, exe

I am stuck with one point , I developed a micro recorder which will record and play back  user action form IE

for example

```
action Go  (http://google.com)
action set q="hiop"
click  button = scr
```

I am saving this script in xml format , when user wish to play back this script he need to load the saved script in my program and click on play button then program play back the script

Now I wish to save this script as batch file or exe or some thing similar  so when user click on it , It will automatically open new instance my program ,load the script and play back it so user dont have to load manually and click on play button

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alter your micro recorder program so that if it is passed a script name on the command line, it will run it directly. Then you can make a bat file of the form:

```
<path to micro recorder/player> <script file>
```

For example, you could have a file search_for_hiop.bat with the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\MicroRecorder\MicroRecorder" "C:\Program Files\MicroRecorder\scripts\search_for_hiop.xml"
```

Clicking on the bat file will execute your micro recorder/player, and run the script.

Comment: Even better, [associate the file type to the application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758090(v=vs.85).aspx) so that you won't need a bat file. You and [peter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18153319/211627) each have a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Hi this is good way simply create a batch file to ope program and load the script in it -- but still oen issue is left to automate Play button of my program

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your script with an extension propritary to your program (eg .rec) that is not used by other programs on your pc or the pc's where you intend to run it.
Then you tell the OS to open your program when this kind of script is run.
In windows this is done by right-clicking such a script in explorer, choose properties and "open with", after which you choose your program. In the other OS this is similar but can't give you the details.
That's all, when you double-click a fiel met the .rec extension your pc starts your program with your script-name as a parameter.

Success !

Comment: I believe the program will need to accept the path to the file as a command line argument in order for this to work. Otherwise, it will just launch your application, but you'll still need to "open" the file whatever method you have in your application.

Comment: yes that is main issue launching program can be done by using something like process.start(myapp.exe) but we need to load and play the respective script as well

Comment: @user501620, If you want to set this all up during installation, then this article may be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user501620, This article may be even more relevant: [How File Associations Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758090(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: hi  all info is very useful in cluding registring file with program etc --
It is also ok to launch application using batch -- but how to configure my application to load a file form command mode any idea and how to instruct my program that when it get launched fmor batch file automatically click on play button

Comment: @user501620: is regular practice in programs, how us some code, perhaps we can help

Answer (score -1):

Try AutoHotkey, With Pulover's Macro recorder.
http://www.autohotkey.net/~Pulover/

This is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi I already developed my Micro record I need to convert my script to exe

Comment: *This is what you're looking for.* <- I love the confidence.